# Proving Sequence is Linearly Independent and Complete in $\ell^2$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

> Let $\{\delta_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be the sequence of standard basis vectors, and for each integer $n \geq 2$ let $z_n$ be the sequence $$z_n = \delta_1 + \delta_n = (1,0,...,,0,1,0,...).$$

> Prove that $\{z_n\}_{n \geq 2}$ is a linearly independent and complete sequence in $\ell^2$.

Complete sequence in this case means $\overline{span}\{z_n\} = \ell^2$.

Attempt using definition of linear independence:

$$\sum_{n \geq 2} c_n z_n = \sum_{n \geq 2} c_n(\delta_1 + \delta_n) = [\sum_{n \geq 2} c_n,c_2,c_3,c_4,...,c_n]$$ and $$[\sum_{n \geq 2} c_n,c_2,c_3,c_4,...,c_n]  = 0 \implies c_1,c_2,..., c_n = 0$$

Not sure where to begin when it comes to proving $z_n$ is complete.

Comment: What do you mean by that summation after the second equality sign in the final equation?

Comment: @dasherman When summing over $n$ we multiply $c_n$ by $\delta_1$ for all $n$ so the first component of the final expression becomes a sum over all constants $c_n$.

Comment: We are in a Hilbert space. To show that a span is complete, you beed only to show that if $\langle x, z_n\rangle=0$ for all n then $x=0$.

Comment: How come? @ArcticChar

Comment: You forgot to define $z_1=\delta_1$. The family $\{z_n\}$ can't be complete without it.